# Problem after migration from Wildfly 10 / Java 9 to Wildfly 24/ Java 16 -> could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Tags: java, primefaces, wildfly

I got this exception when starting my WAR file in the Wildfly 24 server under Java 16 after migrating from Wildfly 10 / Java 9.

I dont understand this Exception.

> `11:37:44,290 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
> 11:37:44,292 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
> 11:37:44,293 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myApplication.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myApplication.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
> ... 8 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
> at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.notNullFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:524)
> at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:207)
> at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:279)
> at deployment.myApplication.war//org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:168)
> at deployment.myApplication.war//org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:230)
> at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1603)
> at deployment.myApplication.war//org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:578)
> at deployment.myApplication.war//org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initStartupFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:547)
> at deployment.myApplication.war//org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:100)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
> ... 10 more
>
> 11:37:44,299 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
> (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
> address: ([("deployment" => "myApplication.war")]) - failure
> description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.deployment.unit."myApplication.war".undertow-deployment" =>
> "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could
> not find backup for factory
> javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory
> javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. "}}`

Comment: Hi! which version of primefaces are you using? have you updated it when going from wf10 to wf24?

Comment: I am using Primefaces 10.

Comment: Is Wildfly 24 EE9? Is it using `jakarta` namespaces instead of `javax`?